# Finding specific text in webpages (with Google?)

Tags: python, perl, google-search

I want to use Google to search for text within the "Experience" section of public LinkedIn profiles that are indexed by Google. What is the best way to do this?

So far I only know how to limit my Google search to the `somesite.com` domain with:

```
site:somesite.com
```

But how would I use it to search within particular sections of the wegpage HTML?
Is this more of a Python/Perl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "HTML Parser" is your answer.

Try [Beautiful Soup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

This is great HTML Parser for Python Language.